# localStorage issue in angular UI with Auth0

Tags: angular, auth0, angular-local-storage

I have a windows application from which users will launch a particular path(`mysite.com/{integerid}/home`) on my angular UI.

I have auth0 authentication setup on my angular UI, so as soon as that above URL launches, I save the parameter `integerid` in localStorage, then the browser redirects to microsoft login for auth0, then comes back to the callback URL where I am retrieving `integerid` and back to `mysite.com/{integerid}/home`.

The problem is due to redirect away from `mysite.com` I think I am losing the value I saved as `integerid` in `localStorage`, so what happens is after authentication the URL that the user is on the URL `mysite.com/null/home`

any idea how I can get around the problem?

Comment: Can you confirm it is actually saved? As long as you set and get the value from localStorage  while being on the same domain, this should work fine. It is probably an implementation issue?

Comment: I am not on the same domain, during authentication I get redirected to login.microsoftonline.com where the user logs in and is redirected to the callback url(which is my domain again).

Comment: FYI, this redirect to microsoft is not a popup window either, its an inplace redirect

Comment: A redirect inbetween is fine, localStorage value will stay. So is your value in localStorage..?